# How to access SOAP API with binding 'transport clientCredentialType="Windows"' in SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

How to access the API's which requires a windows authentication bindings. Trying with NTLM auth type in the soap but still facing an issue with 401 unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can connect with :net_http adapter

```
Savon.client(
        ntlm: ["<user>", "<pwd>", "<domain">],
        wsdl: <wsdl_file_link/local_file>,
        adapter: :net_http,
        open_timeout: 300, 
        read_timeout: 300
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sireesh is it possible to provide a link to the API's or even the WSDL?